# Does a "nonexistent variable" evaluate to the "undefined" value in non-strict code?

Tags: javascript, reference, theory

This paragraph is from the book [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 6th edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do), page 58:

> When any identifier appears by itself in a program, JavaScript
>   assumes it is a variable and looks up its value. If no variable with
>   that name exists, the expression evaluates to the `undefined` value.
>   In the strict mode of ECMAScript 5, however, an attempt to evaluate a
>   nonexistent variable throws a ReferenceError instead.

---

First, let me explain how I interpret some of the phrases used in the paragraph.

**"*... identifier appears by itself in a program, ...*":**

I assume the author means the case where an identifier is parsed as an expression (in which case identifier resolution is performed). For example:

```
function func ( arg ) {
    var local = helper( arg );
}
```

Here `func`, `arg` (which appears twice), `local`, and `helper` are all identifiers, but only `helper` and `arg` (only in its second appearance!) are expressions. Thus, only those two identifiers can cause a reference error.

**"*... no variable with that name exists ...*" and "*nonexistent variable*":**

I assume, the author means an identifier which evaluates to an unresolvable reference.

---

Now, correct me if I'm wrong but...

When an identifier which is parsed as an expression (a *`PrimaryExpression`* to be precise) is evaluated, identifier resolution is performed. The result of this process is always a value of the type Reference. In other words, the identifier will evaluate to a reference.

A reference has a base value and a referenced name. The referenced name is the text of the identifier and the base value is the environment record that has a binding for that name (the scope that contains such a variable). However, if identifier resolution fails to resolve the referenced name, the base value of the reference will be the `undefined` value.

So, a "nonexistent variable" therefore evaluates to a reference which base value is `undefined`.

Notice how the evaluation of a nonexistent variable does not throw a reference error. The error is thrown later when the interpreter retrieves the value of the reference (via `GetValue()`). This, however, may not always occur - for instance, `typeof x` won't retrieve the value of the reference if `x` evaluates to an unresolvable reference, and thus, a reference error is not thrown.

---

The paragraph quoted at the beginning of my question, states that in non-strict code, nonexistent variables evaluate to `undefined`, whereas in strict code evaluation of such an identifier throws a reference error. I believe that both these statements are incorrect - an nonexistent variable evaluates to a reference with a base value of `undefined`, and a reference error is *not* thrown in strict mode.

When the interpreter tries to retrieve the value of such a reference (which may or may not occur depending on the "outer" expression or statement in which the identifier appears in), a reference error *is* thrown. This behavior does *not* differ between non-strict and strict mode.

---

**So, is the paragraph correct?** If not, have I correctly identified the mistake(s)? (Also, if there is a mistake in my text, please correct me.)

Answer (score 2):

*Does a “nonexistent variable” evaluate to the “undefined” value in non-strict code?*

```
> foo;
ReferenceError: foo is not defined
> var x = foo;
ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

This behaviour is also true in strict mode:

```
> (function () { "use strict"; foo; }());
ReferenceError: foo is not defined
> (function () { "use strict"; var x = foo; }());
ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

The only difference that I know of between strict mode and non-strict mode in terms of variable resolution is that when *assigning a variable*, if the variable is not declared, a ReferenceError is thrown in strict mode, however in non-strict mode a global variable is implicitly created.

[Annex C (The strict mode of ECMAScript):](http://es5.github.com/#C)

> Assignment to an undeclared identifier or otherwise unresolvable reference does not create a property in the global object. When a simple assignment occurs within strict mode code, its LeftHandSide must not evaluate to an unresolvable Reference. If it does a ReferenceError exception is thrown (8.7.2).

Comment: You are reading the old spec. They changed it in ES5. Now, a unresolvable reference does have a base value of `undefined`. http://es5.github.com/#x10.2.2.1

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: [I realised myself after posting it :P](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9772726/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even if you declared it using

```js
var someVar;
```

it still evaluates to *undefined*.

Comment: My question is about *nonexistent* variables.

Comment: yes it evaluates to undefined, I answered this already above. I said both non-existent and declared without initialization both are like that

Comment: A declared but uninitialized variable indeed evaluates to `undefined`. Internally, identifier resolution **succeeds** to find the name binding and retrieving its value (via `GetValue()`) results in the `undefined` value (because the variable is uninitialized). However, my point is that this behavior does not apply for "nonexistent variables", the difference being that identifier resolution **fails** do find the name binding in this case. For unresolved references, `GetValue()` doesn't return `undefined`, but throws a reference error. That's the difference.